# Bluetooth headphones on Apple M1 (Monterey) with dual boot, paired on both macOs systems

Tags: macos, bluetooth, monterey, apple-silicon

I have two volumes with macOS Monterey, one for work, one for my private stuff - dual boot.

How can I have the Bluetooth devices connected on the one system also connected to the other system.

At the time I always have to remove and pair again my headphones if I switch the starting volume.

Is there any way to copy the paired devices from the one system to the other? I have access to both volumes.

Any idea or help appreciated.